Angular 16 migration causes material errors

Can't bind to 'htmlFor' since it isn't a known property of 'mat-datepicker-toggle'

Can't bind to 'matDatepicker' since it isn't a known property of 'input'

NG8004: No pipe found with name 'translate'.

If 'mat-form-field' is a Web Component then add 'CUSTOM_ELEMENTS_SCHEMA' to the '@NgModule.schemas' of this component to suppress this message.


error NG8001: 'mat-icon' is not a known element:

If 'mat-icon' is an Angular component, then verify that it is part of this module.

If 'mat-icon' is a Web Component then add 'CUSTOM_ELEMENTS_SCHEMA' to the '@NgModule.schemas' of this component to suppress this message.
assignment


error NG8001: 'mat-datepicker' is not a known element
error NG8002: Can't bind to 'htmlFor' since it isn't a known property of 'mat-datepicker-toggle'.
error NG8002: Can't bind to 'matDatepicker' since it isn't a known property of 'input'.
These type of error occured

Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.
